# Valuebox not getting displayed - shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to display value box in my shiny dashboard using flexdashboard package. Please check my code, the value box is not getting displayed. Please help me on this issue.

UI Code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(flexdashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "test"),

                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu()),

                    dashboardBody(
                                fluidRow(
                                  valueBoxOutput("vbox1", width = 2),
                                  valueBoxOutput("vbox2", width = 2),
                                  valueBoxOutput("vbox3", width = 2),
                                  valueBoxOutput("vbox4", width = 2),
                                  valueBoxOutput("vbox5", width = 2),
                                  valueBoxOutput("vbox6", width = 2))))
```

Server code

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  #valuebox
  output$vbox1 <- renderValueBox({
    d <- 10
    valueBox( d, caption = "Coss")
  })

  output$vbox2 <- renderValueBox({ 
    d <- 42
    valueBox( d,"Ccy")
  })

  output$vbox3 <- renderValueBox({ 
    d <- 75
    valueBox( d,"Cty")})

  output$vbox4 <- renderValueBox({ 
    d <- 21
    valueBox( d,"Dup")})

  output$vbox5 <- renderValueBox({ 
    d <- 34
    valueBox( d,"Inte")})

  output$vbox6 <- renderValueBox({ 
    d <- 56
    valueBox( d,"Acd")})

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

I am getting only the text but not the valuebox.

Thanks
Balaji

Comment: You only want a dashboard with a sidebar? For that you could only use `shiny`. The other two packages have, IMO, in 90 % of the cases no use

Comment: In addition your code works for me. Maybe update all the packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your arguments are the wrong way round in valueBox in the server. The MWE below works for me:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(flexdashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "test"),

                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu()),

                    dashboardBody(
                      fluidRow(
                        valueBoxOutput("vbox1", width = 2),
                        valueBoxOutput("vbox2", width = 2))))

server <- function(input, output) {

  #valuebox
  output$vbox1 <- renderValueBox({
    d <- 10
    valueBox( "Coss", d)
  })

  output$vbox2 <- renderValueBox({ 
    d <- 42
    valueBox("Ccy", d)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi, this code only displays me coss and ccy. But i am not getting the value box

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. This is what I get with values you specify showing beneath the Coss and Ccy in value boxes:

https://imgur.com/a/HGjTuTM

Comment: Please have a look at the updated question, I have posted the image of the dashboard with your code. It is not displaying the valuebox

Comment: That’s odd. Could you share your sessionInfo (i.e share the results of typing sessionInfo() in the console? I’m away from the computer at the moment but will try to look at this again later

Comment: does anyone have a solution for this problem? I have the same problem..

Comment: Does the above code I posted not work? If so, I can't see anything other explanation than this being a version issue

Answer (score 6):

flexdashboard package masks valueBoxOutput() which is a function of the shinydashboard package. So to fix this you should use `shinydashboard::valueBoxOutput` instead of  `valueBoxOutput`

Answer (score 6):

a.lay is almost correct. 
You need the namespace for the server functions as well...

```
shinydashboard::valueBoxOutput('valueBoxA')

 output$valueBoxA <- shinydashboard::renderValueBox({
    shinydashboard::valueBox(
      'Default',
      x
    )
  })
```